# NX: Copy one extra file to build directory

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a project that I've built with [nx](https://nx.dev/) and I'm deploying it to Google App Engine.

It needs `app.yaml` in the same folder.

Is there a way to tell nx builder to copy that extra file to the build directory next to everything else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you figured it out by now, but if anyone is still looking for a solution;

In `project.json` you can specify assets for targets so if you need `app.yaml` you can do something like this:

```json
...
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/js:tsc",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/example",
        "main": "apps/example/src/index.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/example/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "apps/example/*.md",
          "apps/example/src/app.yaml" <-- specify your path here
        ]
      }
    }
...
```

Comment: This will put the app.yaml in the public directory as an assets

Comment: should be the accepted answer imho. this implementation outputs to the root of the dist dir for me.

Comment: You can pass in an object in the `"assets"` array (`{ "glob": "web.config", "input": "src", "output": "."}`) but sadly you cannot copy files to outside the project folder

Comment: It does not work if the file asset is outside the apps folder, in my case i need to copy the **schema.prisma** file in to dist folder but i cannot put it in the project.json

Comment: Doesn't work for angular libraries

Answer (score 1):

If you have to include a file from your project's `root` directory (rather than its `src`), you can use the following in your `project.json`:

```
    ...
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "assets": [
          "apps/administration/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/administration/src/assets",
          {
              "glob": "some-info.yml",
              "input": "apps/my-app/",
              "output": "./"
          },
          ...
```